# Searching for a specific word in my txt file

Tags: c#

I'm making an DoorCode console application to make it easier for me to search and add House addresses and door codes to customers.

so far i have all the addresses in a Txt file. which I can add new addresses and see a list of it in the Console window.
but I want to have a function so I could search for a specific address or code and the program will read from the txt file and print it to the `Console` if the adress was found or not..

Cant find how to make it work :/

btw im kinda new to C# aswell..

thanks..

```
public void Sok()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}SEARCH{1}", l, r);
    Console.WriteLine("ANVÄND INTE Å Ä Ö!");
    Console.WriteLine("Ex: Hagavagen 1");
    Console.Write("ADRESS: ");
    var InputAdress = Console.ReadLine();
    //code here


    Console.WriteLine("{0}SEARCH{1}", l, r);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Search how to use a StreamReader class or how the File.ReadAllLines method works

Answer (score 0):

Ty for answer, fixed it!

```
 public void Sok()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}SEARCH{1}", l, r);
        Console.WriteLine("SKRIV [BACK] FÖR ATT GÅ TILL HUVUDMENYN");
        Console.Write("SÖK EFTER ADRESS, PORTKOD ELLER HUSNUMMER:");
        var InputAdress = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
        {
            if (line.Contains(InputAdress))
            {
                string[] entries = line.Split(',');
                Adress Searching = new Adress();
                Searching.Adresses = entries[0];
                Searching.HusNummer = entries[1];
                Searching.PortKod = entries[2];
                Adresser.Add(Searching);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}FOUND{1}",l, r);
                Console.WriteLine("|ADRESS: {0}", Searching.Adresses);
                Console.WriteLine("|NUMMER: {0}", Searching.HusNummer);
                Console.WriteLine("|PORTKD: {0}", Searching.PortKod);

            }
            else if (InputAdress == "BACK")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}BACK{1}", l, r);
                Console.WriteLine("ÅTERGÅR TILL HUVUDMENYN OM 1SEK.");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}BACK{1}", l, r);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", l, r);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```